# How do I display data from different tables based on the button the user selects in flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables called admin and user that look like this.

```
table name: admin
name|id|password

table name: user
name|id|email|password
```

I have two buttons in my html file called `view user` and `view admin`. I want to return all the contents of the `admin` table when `view admin` is clicked and return all the contents of `user` table when the `view user` is clicked.

This is what my html file looks like

```
<a href="{{ url_for('view_credentials')}}"> <input type="submit"  name="submit_button" value="View Admin">

<a href="{{ url_for('view_credentials')}}"> <input type="submit"   name="submit_button" value="View Tutor">

    {% for item in output %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is what my python file looks like

```
@app.route("/view_credentials", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def view_credentials():

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'View Admin':
            output = db.execute('SELECT * FROM admin').fetchall()
            return render_template("adminDashboard.html", output=output)
        elif request.form['submit_button'] == 'View Tutor':
            output = db.execute('SELECT * FROM login_signup_tutor').fetchall()
            return render_template("adminDashboard.html", output=output)
```

I get this error : `HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'submit_button'`
I am a beginner in flask and trying to understand things around. Please let me know where I went wrong and what should I fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please note to use request.form.get() in place of request.form[]. This will not give you error 404 if submit_button does not exist.

Change your python file to this :

```
@app.route("/view_credentials", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def view_credentials():

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.form.get('submit_button') == 'View Admin':
            output = db.execute('SELECT * FROM admin').fetchall()
            return render_template("adminDashboard.html", output=output)
        elif request.form.get('submit_button') == 'View Tutor':
            output = db.execute('SELECT * FROM login_signup_tutor').fetchall()
            return render_template("adminDashboard.html", output=output)
```

After that you are not getting the value of request.form.get('submit_button') then change the value of 'submit_button' to 'submit' and do the similar changes in routes.py so as : request.form.get('submit').

It worked for me.